# How to know which of two APs I am connected to?

Tags: networking, windows-8, wireless-networking, wireless-access-point, wireless-roaming

I have two acess points on my LAN. I suspect that sometimes, when I am far from one AP and close to another, my computer is connected to the furthest one. I judge this by very low signal quality.

How can I find out which one of the access points I am connected to?

Is it possible to force roaming?

Answer (score 1):

To identify the access point you are connected to you can use a Wi-Fi scanner, for example, [inSSIDer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/InSSIDer). That would give you a good overview of your wireless network as well.

Or, if you are comfortable with command line and don't want to install additional tools, you can find out the BSSID of the access point you are connected to using `netsh wlan show interfaces`.